# How to choose feature selection method? By data or some rules?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have been using some feature selection methods individually, e.g.RFE OR Select K best, for multi-label classification. Is there a technique or method can be used into choosing a feature selection method dynamically? for instance, according to the statistics of test data or some rule-based approach?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but you could try each one and cross validate it against some test data. It should be fairly trivial to script this.

I don't know of any better way of picking a feature selection algorithm than this, but it can bias you towards the test data you've used.

Comment: I've tested each of them and did the cross validation on them. Yeah, that definitely depends on the data, but how to choose feature selection methods according to data attribute or performance? You have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These [answers may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566309/find-right-features-in-multiclass-svm-without-pca/29571371#29571371).

My assumption about the feature statistics is: maximal distances between means of values between the classes and minimal variance of values for one class classify a good feature.

I start with small learning set, test this assumption and increase the learning set if results look promising.

The final optimization is the histogram of means comparison. Features with similar histograms are removed. Those are redundant features which decrease (at least on SVM) the accuracy considerable (5-10%).

With this approach I gain 95% of accuracy on my data-set of 5 classes, 600 instances. The training takes < 1h. Manual training used to gained 98% with many days of experimenting.

Comment: I guess your method is similar to PCA ( Principal Component Analysis), I used it before for feature reduction. Yeah, I have tested some feature selection approaches also with SVM, they have different performance.